# changing the styling of a parent and parent's parent of an active element, using fullPage.js callback

Tags: jquery, parent, styling, fullpage.js

I have  a site that utilises fullPage.js ( https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js ) as well as a sidebar menu for navigation between sections, so the user can use the mousewheel to mover down or select the sections on the sidebar.

As the user scrolls, the menu section that is currently active is highlighted. However in **Section 2** the menu expans to show 5 topics grouped into 2 catagories. I want the sub catagory, as well as the section, to be marked active as well as the topic.

Here is an example of what i have so far, using jQuery:
http://jsfiddle.net/rwde78ts/1/

im using the callback "afterSlideLoad" to call a function that changes the CSS of both the parent of the active element (the sub catagory) and the parents parent (the section) to mark them as active.

Heres the code I have so far, which is not working:

```
afterSlideLoad: (function(){
             $(".active").parent().css("color", "black");
             $(".active").parent().parent().css("color", "black");
         })
```

does anyone know what Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quickly answer your question I will first provide solution.

Although this is not best practice, and not helping you learn the right approach to design html structure and traverse the DOM in efficient and quick way, it will solve this specific problem.

If it was all designed better, this might not require Javascript at all and CSS would be perfect solution.

I do not want to explain How my solution work, so you will have the opportunity to learn from this.

I replaced the following tow lines:

```
afterSlideLoad:(function(){
  $(".active").parent().css("color", "black");
  $(".active").parent().parent().css("color", "black");
})
```

To this. this is broken to lines, for better understanding. [of-course this works in code too.]):

```
   afterLoad: function(){
            /* Here comes your previous code... */

            console.log('afterSlideLoad Changed to afterLoad');
            $('.inlinedColor')
            .css('color','gray')
            .removeClass('inlinedColor');

            $('li.active')
            .prevAll('span.year')
            .first()
            .add(
                $('li.active')
                .parents('li')
                .find('>a span span')
            )
            .addClass('inlinedColor')
            .css('color','black');
         }
```

All the above available here: http://jsfiddle.net/rwde78ts/10/

If you did not managed to figure it out on your own, do not hesitate to ask, so i could explain line by line.

Comment: thank you, that works well, may I ask what does the console.log do in this code?

Comment: simple words: log message to the console. read more here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console